# Configure Firebase SDK in multivariant project

Tags: android, firebase

I tried to add Firebase to existing project with quite complex setup (2 variants, +2 dev) and was wondering, how google-services.json should be used? Is there manual way of adding service config? I had the same problem with GCM, it works fortunatelly but I spent quite some time digging on stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you explain more about what differs between your variants?  In general you want to add all of your variants to the same Firebase project in the console.  Then you can put a google-services.json in `app/src/<flavorName>` for each one to get custom configuration if you need it.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your reply. Ok, I see now, I was adding it according to docs (If you haven't done so already, copy this into your project's module folder, typically app/). Haven't thought to add into variants' folders

Comment: There are some docs on how the plugin works here (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) but I need to update them for the latest Firebase changes.  Still, the general guidelines are true.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a new post on the Firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html) about the relationships between apps and projects, and how that relates to your Android build variants.  Hopefully it will demystify how things work.  At the very least you should know that you can have all your Firebase apps defined in a single google-services.json that can apply to each of your variants (if they're all in the same project), or you can put a whole different google-services.json file in your project for each variant, if they are in different projects.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Android Studio?

You use Android Studio and Gradle and then

you can use google-services.josn file.

The google-services.json file is generally placed in the app/ directory (at the root of the Android Studio app module)

You can set both GCM and FCM .

[The Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)